# SQL Query Giving Unique Fields Per User With Count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I'm trying to figure out a query that counts the number of times a user has given a unique answer and returns the user, answer, and count of those answers. The table looks like this:

```
Table Likes
ID   Username   Choice
1    Bobby      Cat
2    Tina       Rabbit
3    Bobby      Rabbit
4    Alex       Goose
5    Bobby      Cat
6    Alex       Goose
7    Alex       Dog
```

After running the query, I hope to get each user along with his choices and the count of each like so:

```
Result
Username   Choice      Count(Selection)
Bobby      Rabbit      1
Bobby      Cat         2
Tina       Rabbit      1
Alex       Goose       2
Alex       Dog         1
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
SELECT Username, Choice, Count(Choice) FROM Likes GROUP BY Username
```

But this is not quite right.

Comment: What happens when you add `Choice` into your `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **add Choice** in `Group by` to count the number of times a user has given a unique answer. **Without choice** in `Group by` u will get the count of answers given by each user

```
SELECT Username,
       Choice,
       Count(Choice)
FROM   Likes
GROUP  BY Username,
          choice
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful.

```
 SELECT Username, Choice, Count(Choice) AS CountSelection 
 FROM Likes 
 GROUP BY Username, Choice
```